# How to upload the audio file using php

Tags: php

i wanted to upload the mp3 file to the related folder name /uploads/ inside my project folder. But something not working correctly in php. Image file are uploading without any error but when i tried to upload the mp3 file its not working.

Here is my html form

```
<form action="act_songs.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php 
                if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
                    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
                    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
                }
                 ?>
                <p>
                <label>Song Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="sng-title">
                </p>
                <p>
                <label>Song Name</label>
                <input type="file" name="mp3" accept="audio/*" runat="server">
                </p>
                <p>
                <input type="submit" name="add-song" value="ADD">
                </p>
</form>
```

And here is my php code

```
if (isset($_POST['add-song'])) {
$title = $_POST['sng-title'];
$audio = $_FILES['mp3']['name'];
$audio_type = $_FILES['mp3']['type'];
$audio_size = $_FILES['mp3']['size'];
$tmp_location = $_FILES['mp3']['tmp_name'];
$audio_url = "../uploads/".$audio;
if ($type == '.mp3' || $type == '.wav') {
    if ($size <= 5000) {
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_location, $audio_url);  
    }
}

if (!empty($title)) {
    $sql = "insert into `tbl_songs` (`title`,`songs`) values ('$title','$audio_url')";
    $sql_run = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($sql_run) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert'>Record Saved</div>";
        header('location:songs.php');
    }

    else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert'>Record Cannot Saved</div>";
        header('location:add-songs.php?invalid');
    }
}

else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert'>Title Must be requiired.</div>";
    header('location:add-songs.php?invalid');
}
```

}

What is the problem i am unable to debug the problem. If anybody have solution  then place your answer

Comment: whats not working? what are the errors? how have you tried to debug it so far?

Comment: You code has a variety of logic paths which would "silently fail".  Debug and find out what's actually happening.  For example, what happens if you upload an MP3 file that's larger than `5000`?

Comment: when i tried to upload the mp3 files the file get failed only the folder path and file name is inserting on database table but not any  file is uploded on my /uploads/ folder. what will be the reason for this

Comment: what's the mp3 file size ? what are the configured file upload size limits in the php configuration and maximum post size on the webserver ?

Comment: $type is undefined